# How to write log before instalation

Tags: logs, system-installation

My computer crashes while trying to load the kernel from a LiveCD with the message "unable to handle kernel paging request". I'd like to reproduce the error output on a forum to get some ideas on where to dig, but I can't figure out how to save that trace except by taking a picture with a camera. Is there some option to save the output on a hard drive, or at least allow scrolling to the beginning of the error? I currently have Windows and Ubuntu 9.10 installed, and I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04. The same error happens with other Linux distributions (openSUSE 13.1, Linux Mint 16).

Answer (score 0):

Possibly [kexec](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/geoff/petitboot/kexec-man-11.10.21-g90da2c37.txt) is your friend in this case.

Though I'm not sure as I have not tried

Comment: How does this relate to the question?